# Logo overlapping in css?

Tags: css

Why is the logo here having a slight overlap at the bottom portion? The CSS and HTML are given below. I've tried overriding the css properties respective to the logo `<li>` element. but it didn't work.

[`working fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/66eKE/)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li class="logo">
                    <a href="#" style="padding:0;">
                        <img src="logo.png" />
                    </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    #nav li {
        width: 20%;
        float: right;
        text-align: center;
    }

        #nav li a {
            display: block;
            padding: 0.5em 5px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #F2F2F2;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(51,51,51,0.3);
            box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(51,51,51,0.3);
        }

    #nav a:link, #nav a:visited {
        background-color: #071726;
    }

    #nav a:hover, #nav a:active, #nav a:focus {
        background-color: #326773;
    }
```

Comment: Make demo here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/66eKE/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MBKjW/ but here, the <li> element for logo was reduced.

Comment: logo image is missing..How do we find that logo overlapping?

Comment: its not just the logo. the li > a element for logo itself is either overlapping or its size's reduced.

Comment: try this : http://jsfiddle.net/66eKE/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

http://jsfiddle.net/66eKE/3/

```
#nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(51,51,51,0.3);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(51,51,51,0.3);
    background: #000;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#nav li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 19%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #F2F2F2;
}

#nav a:link, #nav a:visited {
}

#nav a:hover, #nav a:active, #nav a:focus {
    background-color: #326773;
}
```

This makes it so you can resize your logo to whatever you want. The menu item may be floating outside the div. In that case you either need to float the parent, hide the parent with overflow, or clear the float.

**Refactor**
I refactored a few things such as the drop shadow and background color on the parent. This allows the majority of the effect to be dependent on the parent div rather than the individual items. I'm only assuming here though. Do you have a photoshop mockup of what you want? Gives us a better idea of what you need for CSS.